# Active Record - Joining same table multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model `A` which belongs to my `User` model. I also have a model `B`, which belongs to my `B` model and also my `User` model (those are two different users, like doctor and patient). What I would like to do is some query like this:

```
B.joins(:user, {a: :user}).where("patient.name = 'some condition' or doctor.name='some other condition'")
```

The point here is: how can I specify that the users.name I'm querying is the one which is associated to A or B model? 
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this could work? (I haven't tested the code)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :doctors
  has_many :patients, through: :doctors
end

class Doctor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :patients
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :user
end

Patient.joins(user: {doctors: :user}).where("patient.name = 'some condition' or doctor.name='some other condition'")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create new classes named `Patient` and `Doctor` that inherit from `User`, then refer to users as patients and doctors instead of generic users.

```
class Doctor < User
  has_many :a
end
class Patient < User
  has_many :b
end
```

This is Single Table Inheritance:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: But doing that only for one query? Doesn't seems to worth... guess there's probably a better way to query that using active record